# passing correlated values to a function in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

i have this function :

```
FUNCTION balance_gl_s(p_Date VARCHAR2,   p_Ledgerid NUMBER)
```

I want to use a function in a query like this:

```
select *
from ledgers l
cross apply (select *
            from table(gl_balance_s.balance_gl_s(13970914, l.ledger_fk)))
```

I googled it and I found out that this syntax is valid after 12c release and I'm using 11g.
Is there any other solution for what I want to do? Thank you in advance.

Comment: A DATE value as number?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit it's persian date and it get converted into gregorian date in the function but obviously that's not the point.

Comment: @APC it's about 300 ledger_fk and each one should return 1 up to 73 records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create another function and call the first function in a loop:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION balance_gl_s_outer(p_Date VARCHAR2) RETURN your_type

PIPELINED IS
Rec your_type;
cursor cr is
 select l.ledger_fk from ledgers l;

BEGIN

for rr in cr loop

 FOR Rec IN (select *
              from table(gl_balance_s.balance_gl_s(p_Date,
                                                   rr.ledger_fk))) LOOP
  PIPE ROW(Rec);

  END LOOP;
end loop;

end;
```

Comment: as the OP mentioned it's only available after 12c release but the desired result will be provided by the above function.